# High frequency audio on Android

Tags: java, android, audio

I recently started playing with AudioTrack on Android and came across some issues playing tones I am generating. If i switch from a sinusoidal with a frequency of 18kHz to a sinusoidal with frequency of 19kHz frequency, there is an audible clicking sound that occurs when there is a change in frequency. The entire piece is played from a static buffer, which is played from AudioTrack. The sampling rate is 44.1kHz, and each sinusoidal is sampled 44100 times, resulting in about a second of play for each.

Even further, I generated the same tones on Audacity and could still hear a small click when the frequency changed. The noise itself sounds like the speaker turning on and off, but I am unsure.

Any ideas on what could eliminate this clicking noise?

Comment: Most likely you have an instantaneous jump in your waveform.  You should ensure that's not the case.

Comment: Are there two sinuses or are you changing the values as you play the sound?

Comment: If you're outputting to the internal loudspeaker/earpiece or 3.5mm headset, keep in mind that the hardware codecs of most mobile platforms have a native sampling rate of 48000 Hz. So there will be a 44.1->48 kHz resampler somewhere in the system (for example on the multimedia DSP). which might in some cases have a fairly sharp roll-off at 18 or 19 kHz (based on some acoustic measurements I've seen, although that was over a year ago).

Comment: I don't see why this question was closed.

Comment: Neither do I...oh well these are some great ideas and thoughts, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The click is most likely happening because you have a discontinuous jump between the 18kHz wave and the 19kHz wave.

To correct the problem, wait until the 18kHz sine wave reaches zero, switch frequencies, and then begin drawing the 19kHz wave from zero, *in the same direction that the 18kHz wave ended.*  So, if the 18kHz wave approached zero from the positive side, you would begin drawing the 19kHz wave towards the negative side first.

Comment: If the sine never hits 0 because we are taking discrete points, is something near 0 alright? I still have a clicking noise doing it this way, but it is toned down somewhat.

Comment: @Batman You could also try gradually shifting from 18kHz to 19kHz over a short period of time, e.g. use `sin(18000*t*2*pi)*(1-a) + sin(19000*t*2*pi)*a` as your waveform, where `a` is 0 initially and smoothly shifts to 1.

Comment: This was my next though, thanks for the suggests, I'll let you all know what works out.